# Multiple limit based on condition

Tags: ms-access

I just wondering how can I do multiple limit based on different condition from 1 table.

E.g.: I have 100 students with random numbers of male and female. I want to select only top 25 male and 25 female.

How that can be done?

Comment: Is it access or MySQL?

Comment: it might be helpful if you could provide more information, such as the table definition and some data. Furthermore mysql is not ms-access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `union`

```
select top 25 * from students where gender = 'M'
union all 
select top 25 * from students where gender = 'F'
```